# Spring Security, how to manage SpringSecurityChain from url request?

Tags: java, spring, security, jpa

In spring security for manage urls and authorities used SecuirtyFilterChain. How to manage autority linked with url from request. Something like: request: localhost:8080/authority/1(this is id authority in db)?method=Post?url=/producst/add
to generate in SecurityFilterChain somethins like this:
.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/producst/add").hasAuthority("ADMIN")

Maybe need to make custom SecurityFilterChain?

Someone know it's possible to make? Becouse i don't know for what make autorities saved in db if you can't manage out of app this new authorities to link in app.

Don't know how to normal make my question for google search.

Comment: Yes you can, should you probably not as it is insecure as ****.